# Transformation of poses between camera frame and base frames

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Many variations of these questions seem to have been asked quite a few times, however, I was not able to find and compute the right answer for my problem.

I am trying out a custom picking of an object using a Robotic Arm. I have a separate perception module that detects objects and estimates the pose for grasping. It, however (as expected) is in the camera frame and follows image processing convention of coordinate frames, i.e. with `right: +x-axis, forward: +z-axis, down: +y-axis`. From this perception module, I get two values - `3x3` Rotation matrix and `1x3` translation vector.

Example `T1` :

```
Tra: [0.09014122 0.16243269 0.6211668 ]
 Rot: [[ 0.          0.03210089 -0.99948463]
 [ 0.          0.99948463  0.03210089]
 [ 1.         -0.          0.        ]]
```

(i.e. I have to grasp at that location and in that orientation)

My robot to camera transform is understandably in the right hand coordinate system. Here is an example of the same, say `T2`:

```
translation: 
  x: 0.0564581200121
  y: 0.318823912978
  z: 0.452250135698
rotation: 
  x: -0.6954818376
  y: 0.693982204231
  z: -0.13156524004
  w: 0.13184954074
```

Now, to get the pose of the object from the robot, is a simple transformation `T2 times T1`. However, `T1` follows a different convention from T2.

How would I go about this ? A detailed explanation using this example will be highly appreciated! I am trying to understand from scratch, hence I would prefer to arrive at a transformation matrix on my own to apply to the above ones to get the final pose

Additional note: The robot to camera transformation is using the `depth_camera_optical_frame` to `base_link`. Should I use this or just `depth_camera_frame`?

I have checked out similar issues like [33091](https://answers.ros.org/question/33091/doubts-about-interpreting-xyz-from-kinect/), [gazebo-4226](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4266/gazebo-15-libgazebo_openni_kinectso-pointcloud-data-is-rotated-and-flipped/?answer=24822#post-id-24822), and other ones.
However, all of them seem to give solutions for 3D points, and I could not find any that is applicable for the pose transformation matrix.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352485/transformation-of-poses-between-camera-frame-and-base-frames/) by [ThreeForElvenKings](https://answers.ros.org/users/54382/threeforelvenkings/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2020-05-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is just a matter of unifying the representations of T1 and T2. Quaternions are the preferred orientation in ROS, and the [TF C++](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html#a2a84d61a0dbba017cdc7a56c8cbf7743) and [Python APIs](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/python/transformations.html) offer methods to convert between them and rotation matrices. But you shouldn't bother multiplying transformation matrices directly in ROS. TF was made to take care of this for you.

The easiest way to get the position of your object should be:

1. Create a `PoseStamped` object called `p`.
2. Set the `frame_id` of its `header` to `depth_camera_optical_frame` (the frame that your object is detected in)
3. Set `p.pose.position` to the translation vector you posted, and `p.pose.orientation` to the quaternion that you obtain from the rotation matrix.
4. To obtain the quaternion in C++, set the rotation of a Transform with [this function](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transform.html#aca40971dcc5d19cf0c0f7c7ed3906d18) and [this matrix type](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Matrix3x3.html), then get the quaternion from [this function](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transform.html#a6492cc6ec2fbbc2e594a2233eeac7c6a). In Python, simply use [quaternion_from_matrix](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/python/transformations.html#tf.transformations.quaternion_from_matrix). Don't forget that `tf` and `geometry_msgs` quaternions are [not the same](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html#a59d2fcbc5720f31a5e330f0e7c4a3721).
5. Use the `transformPose` function of the [TransformListener](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1TransformListener.html) ([Python API](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html)) to transform `p` to the frame `base_link`.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2020-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ThreeForElvenKings](https://answers.ros.org/users/54382/threeforelvenkings/) on 2020-05-21**:
Oh the 4th point is where I guess I was going wrong. Thanks a ton!